# Pandas aggregation ignoring NaN's

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, aggregate, nan

I aggregate my Pandas dataframe: `data`. Specifically, I want to get the average and sum `amount`s by tuples of [`origin` and `type`]. For averaging and summing I tried the numpy functions below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
result = data.groupby(groupbyvars).agg({'amount': [ pd.Series.sum, pd.Series.mean]}).reset_index()
```

My issue is that the `amount` column includes `NaN`s, which causes the `result` of the above code to have a lot of `NaN` average and sums.

I know both `pd.Series.sum` and `pd.Series.mean` have `skipna=True` by default, so why am I still getting `NaN`s here?

I also tried this, which obviously did not work:

```
data.groupby(groupbyvars).agg({'amount': [ pd.Series.sum(skipna=True), pd.Series.mean(skipna=True)]}).reset_index()
```

**EDIT:** 
Upon @Korem's suggestion, I also tried to use a `partial` as below:

```
s_na_mean = partial(pd.Series.mean, skipna = True)    
data.groupby(groupbyvars).agg({'amount': [ np.nansum, s_na_mean ]}).reset_index()
```

but get this error:

```
error: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: Could you post some example data?  Also, to start with, rather than `pd.Series.sum` - just use `'sum'` - the code should take a faster path.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to use `pd.Series.sum` jus becasue it had a `skipna` option. Reading @Korem's answer, I now use `np.nansum`. But `np.nanmean` is not available in my version (1.7.1) of numpy.I will try to post representative data, which may take a while.

Answer (score 18):

Use numpy's [nansum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) and [nanmean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
from numpy import nansum
from numpy import nanmean
data.groupby(groupbyvars).agg({'amount': [ nansum, nanmean]}).reset_index()
```

As a workaround for older version of numpy, and also a way to fix your last try:

When you do `pd.Series.sum(skipna=True)` you actually call the method. If you want to use it like this you want to define a [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). So if you don't have `nanmean`, let's define `s_na_mean` and use that:

```
from functools import partial
s_na_mean = partial(pd.Series.mean, skipna = True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I use **numpy-1.7.1-py2.7-win32.egg**, it does not like `nanmean` throwing the error: `'module' object has no attribute 'nanmean'`. (I just checked, `nanmean` is new in verison 1.8.0

Comment: But `np.nansum` seems to be added in version 1.8.0 as well. It is curious that I do not get the same error for that...

Comment: Thanks Korem, I tried this but it did not work, I edited my question, giving the error. Also, isn't `skipna=True` for `pd.Series.mean` by default anyways?

Comment: @Zhubarb it is on by default, which suggest that the problem you're seeing is not where you think it is.

Comment: You are right, I tried this, which ran: `data.groupby(groupbyvars).agg({'amount': [ np.nansum, lambda x: pd.Series.mean(x,skipna=True)]}).reset_index()` but  still get `NaN`s. I will investigate further. Maybe those are the cases for which all I have is NaN..

Comment: pandas doc : "skipna : boolean, default True", 
"Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA"

Answer (score 3):

It might be too late but anyways it might be useful for others.

Try apply function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def nan_agg(x):
    res = {}

    res['nansum'] = x.loc[ not x['amount'].isnull(), :]['amount'].sum()
    res['nanmean'] = x.loc[ not x['amount'].isnull(), :]['amount'].mean()

    return pd.Series(res, index=['nansum', 'nanmean'])

result = data.groupby(groupbyvars).apply(nan_agg).reset_index()
```